# How to disply answer sets without facts

Tags: compilation, logic, reasoning, answer-set-programming, clingo

Please, can someone tell me how to display all the resulted answer sets in a logic program compiled with Clingo , without displaying the facts, i need to see only rules without facts.

Answer (score 0):

To display answer sets without any facts, we use the -c option.

For example:

clingo -c num=0 answer-set.lp

The output would be:

clingo version 5.4.0 Reading from answer-set.lp answer-set()

To display answer sets without any facts, we use the -c option. For example: clingo -c num=0 answer-set.lp The output would be: clingo version 5.4.0 Reading from answer-set.lp answer-set()